# Monitor Service Calls in play ( Metrics and Graphite)

Tags: playframework-2.0, metrics, graphite

I am working on sending application statistics to Graphite using metrics .
I am using the following plugin to do this stuff :

https://github.com/kenshoo/metrics-play

I have written a Global.scala that reads graphite host, port , prefix and dump these details to graphite server.

My question :

1. As part of application, we have several rest api calls and we want to monitor all these service calls (Service A, Service B, Service C, etc). Any ideas how to write some code in scala to monitor each of these services or any resource you can point me to ?